# What are some techniques or tools for debugging JavaScript in Dreamweaver CS5?

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I see that DW reports errors as I type them.  Is there a way to trace to a console at runtime like can be done with Firebug? What are some other techniques or tools for debugging JavaScript in Dreamweaver CS5?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The closest you can get is to run in Live Code/Live View mode which will upload the page to your testing server and DW will attempt to display it like a browser with the code running in a split window.  But this isn't anywhere close to a runtime console and tends to die silently on errors.

Testing in a browser is really your best course of action when dealing with Dreamweaver.